# JPA/Hibernate, Delete on ManyToMany doesn't delete join table records

Tags: hibernate, jpa

this has been asked a number of other times, but I can't figure out an answer in my case.

I have this class http://tinyurl.com/nrhbnna, having a ManyToMany relationship to OntologyEntry. Here it is a fragment:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class FreeTextTerm extends Identifiable
{
  ...
  @ManyToMany( targetEntity = OntologyEntry.class, cascade = { 
    CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH } )
  @JoinTable ( joinColumns = @JoinColumn ( name = "owner_id" ), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn ( name = "oe_id" ) )
  @SuppressWarnings ( "unchecked" )
  public <OE extends OntologyEntry> Set<OE> getOntologyTerms ()
  ...
}
```

I don't have the symmetric side OntologyEntry.freeTextTerms(), cause I don't need it and they don't work well with polymorphism.

Now, when I delete records from subclasses in HQL (eg, from ExperimentalPropertyValue, http://tinyurl.com/mydgnwr, or Unit, http://tinyurl.com/lu28sfu), Hibernate completely ignores records in the respective join tables (eg, it ignores unit_onto_entry, when I delete Unit instances, verified via logs), resulting in foreign key violations, if the current owner has such links.

I already know this happens when you attempt to delete from the non-owner side of a many-to-many relation, but that's not the case here. Moreover, I don't think CascadeType.DELETE would help here, cause I do not want to delete children (ie, ontology entries), just the links to them.

So, is Hibernate as crap as to ignore such links? (After years of experience, I really hate Hibernate). Do I have to use @PreRemove, as explained in http://tinyurl.com/kgpk92a, or is there a cleaner solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the *relevant* code in your question.

Comment: Thanks JB. The relevant code is in GitHub and linked above

Comment: Precisely: it's not in your question as it should be.

Comment: I mean that the relevant code should be, verbatim, in the question. Not as link to github. One should be able to read the question and only the question, now or in 2 years (when the github project won't exist anymore, or the code has changed radically), and find the relevant code.

Comment: I'm very sure the project will remain there and I don't agree with the policy of copy/pasting tons of code, but I'm going to do that.

Comment: By the way, if SO is concerned of link persistence, they should cache them automatically, like many scientific journals do.

Comment: You shouldn't copy tons of code. You should copy the **relevant** code. That is another reason why linking to github files is **not** a good solution. Another related reason is that you should make the job of the people that are eager to help you for free as easy as possible.

Comment: The relevant code can be tons :-) Anyway, I've done it, could I and people dealing with the same problem have the down-vote amended? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that batch statements in HQL are rubbish, they completely ignore relationship dependencies: http://twasink.net/2005/04/20/differences-in-behaviour-between-hibernate-delete-queries-and-the-old-way/. I'm so frustrated with ORM...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from using @ManyToMany inside a @MappedSuperclass. MappedSuperclass is not itself an entity and it is assumed different (multiple) classes extend it and use the definitions put inside. If all child entities (with different primary keys sequences) would use the same manytomany link-table problems most likely would occur.

As I see in entity "ExperimentalPropertyValue" you try to use Single-Table inheritance strategy.

A solution would be to give up on MappedSuperclass, and move the inheritance definitions to FreeTextTerm that you also define as entity.

Comment: No, because there are other hierarchies, mapped with other tables and strategies. I think the problem is that HQL ignores @ManyToMany altogether, investigating on it.

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up anyway.